# threading.enumerate() doesn't show all running threads (Python, Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have some threads running in a python program on windows os.
I want to set a button 'Clear' who stops all threads work.
Threads from Logic class are shown in `threads_list = threading.enumerate()`
but Threads Gui class are not, and I know for sure that they are running (I see it on the gui)

I managed to stop Gui threads work from `MainFrame.stop_threads()` by accessing the global boolean that ThreadB checks and changing it to True

- all threads have been started before ive asked them to stop
- regular while loop with no 'after' command doesnt change the labels' text

My question is, although I managed to solve the problem with a workaround, I want to know the reason why ThreadB is not in thrads_list, **I suspect that it is not there because** im using 'after' command:

```
self.msg_label.after(1000, self.change_text)
```

**I would like that ThreadB will also be  in the list returned by threading.enumerate(), how can I solve it?**

This is the structure and code that is needed for my question:

Logic\ThreadA.py

```
class ThreadA(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        # some uninteresting code
```

Gui\FeedbackWigets.py

```
class ThreadB(Thread):
    def __init__(self, msg_label):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.msg_label= msg_label
        self.counter = 0

    def change_text(self):
        match self.counter:
                case 0:
                    self.msg_label.config(text="Inserting Graphs.")
                case 1:
                    # config label
                # more cases

            self.counter += 1
            self.counter %= 3

            if DecipherBin.stop_graphs_bool:
                self.msg_label.config(text="Finished inserting Graphs")
                return
            self.msg_label.after(1000, self.change_text)
    
    def run(self):
        self.msg_label.after(0, self.change_text)
```

Gui\MainFrame.py

```
    class GuiLogic(ttk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, main_window):
            super().__init__()
            self.main_window = main_window
            thread_a = Logic.ThreadA()
            thread_b = Gui.ThreadB()
            thread_a.start()
            thread_b.start()
            stop_threads()
            ...

        def stop_threads(self):
            thread_list = threading.enumerate()
            print(f"thread list: {thread_list}")
            for thread in thread_list:
                if thread.name != 'MainThread' and 'pydev' not in thread.name:
                    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread.ident, ctypes.py_object(SystemExit))
                    thread.join()
    
            thread_list = threading.enumerate()
            print(f"thread list after remove: {thread_list}")
```

main.py

```
...
main_window = Tk()
GuiLogic(main_window) # starts program
```

**What I have tried: **

1. search for threading.enumerate() bugs
2. read threading.enumerate() documentation:

> Return a list of all Thread objects currently
> active. The list includes daemonic threads and dummy thread objects
> created by current_thread(). It excludes terminated threads and
> threads that have not yet been started. However, the main thread is
> always part of the result, even when terminated.

the threads Im interested to stop have been started before the moment they were asked to be closed.

3. instead of `run(self): self.msg_label.after(0, self.change_text)` i've tried:

```
def run(self):
    while not DecipherBin.stop_graphs_bool:
        match self.counter:
            case 0:
                self.master.config(text="Inserting Graphs.")
            # more cases
        self.counter += 1
        self.counter %= 3

        sleep(1)
    self.master.config(text="Finished Inserting Graphs")
```

Comment: When you run the thread with the while loop, you still encounter the same behavior as with after? Could you provide a [mre], so we don't have to write a script to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Does this thread_list = list(threading.enumerate()) help? I didn't test it.

Comment: The constructor for ThreadB requires an argument, and you're not passing one.

Comment: The real reason for your observed situation is that ThreadB is probably already finished.  It does only one thing, the call to `after`, and that's a request to TkInter to make an immediate callback to the method `change_text`.  Then the thread exits.  The callback occurs in the main thread, which is the only context for TkInter execution.  Just because `change_text` is a function in class ThreadB doesn't make it execute in ThreadB.  The thread itself begins at the method `run`, and its line of execution is whatever functions it calls.